# TypeError: ribbonFrame is undefined

Tags: exm

I am using `Sitecore 9.0.2`. I have created `custom EXM template` using below links:

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/exm/90/email-experience-manager/en/walkthrough--building-a-custom-message-template.html

**What I have done so far**

- Created custom template for newsletter
- Created custom layout
- Created custom component (Quick Links)

**What I have done so for Quick Link component**

- I am using controller rendering
- For the `Quick link` component, I will have a parent data source and I can have multiple child items.
- I am getting parent data source and binding child item which is working fine
- Also In parent data source template's standard value, I have assigned child item
- In core DB, I have created `custom experience button` `New` to create child item and also selected `New` in rendering

**Issue**

My issue is that when I have added component from EXM template and when I am trying to create new child item, in the console it is showing an error message and allowing to add a child item
[image]

[image]

```
TypeError: ribbonFrame is undefined[Learn More] ExperienceEditor.js:463:17
    getRibbonWindow http://onesitecore.local/-/speak/v1/ExperienceEditor/ExperienceEditor.js:463
    getApp http://onesitecore.local/-/speak/v1/ExperienceEditor/ExperienceEditor.js:467
    initialized http://onesitecore.local/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/Dialogs/InsertPage/InsertPagePageCode.js:9
    run http://onesitecore.local/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Assets/lib/core/1.1/sitecore-1.0.2.js:685
    runPageCode http://onesitecore.local/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Assets/lib/core/1.1/sitecore-1.0.2.js:986
    run http://onesitecore.local/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Assets/lib/core/1.1/sitecore-1.0.2.js:1010
    execCb http://onesitecore.local/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Assets/lib/core/2.0/deps/require.js:1650
    check http://onesitecore.local/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Assets/lib/core/2.0/deps/require.js:866
    enable http://onesitecore.local/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Assets/lib/core/2.0/deps/require.js:1143
    init http://onesitecore.local/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Assets/lib/core/2.0/deps/require.js:774
    localRequire http://onesitecore.local/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Assets/lib/core/2.0/deps/require.js:1416
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use below link to download the patch file to fix this issue:

1. If you do not have `Experience Accelerator (SXA)` module installed, use below link:
   https://sitecore.box.com/s/6lrwqkwkjyq6cppbk5qrg3vfamfrolzg
2. If you have `SXA installed`, use below link instead of above:
   https://sitecore.box.com/s/uqkmvuernr6kv56lyopt8t8zevui47lo